# MS Word macro to replace text from list

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I need to print about 50 forms that are all nearly identical besides one number. Would it be possible to make a macro that could pull from some table, fill in the blank on the Word document, then make a new document and filling in that blank--continuing the process until the list is finished?

I was thinking maybe a variable to sit in the table and then some sort of Find and Replace macro that would find the variable, then pull from some database (or Notepad, Excel, whatever) the value to replace it.

Any ideas? I'm not terribly experienced with macros unfortunately.

Comment: That's called a merge, and is a built-in function of Word. No Macro required. I suppose a Macro may be helpful for more advanced functions, but the basic Merge function should do what you've described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Word has had a "Merge" function for a very long time.

Seriously, I learned on MS Word running on Windows 3.1 in the early 90's and one of the lessons was on the Merge function.

You'll find the Merge function Mailings ribbon, and while it is designed for creating form letters and envelopes, it also works for many other merge functions.

This is a very mature and capable system in Word, however, if it does not have the specific features you need, like the rest of Word it can be harnessed using the Macro function.